# PHP OOP: Accessing Variables

Tags: php

I have the following "Student" Class:

```
class Student {
    public $user_id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $info = $this->studentInfo($user_id);
        $this->name = $info['name'];
        $this->is_instructor = $info['is_instructor'];
        $this->user_id = $info['id'];
    }

    public static function studentInfo($id) {
        global $db;

        $u = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db[students] WHERE id='$id'"));
        if($u) {
             return $u;
        }
    }        

    public static function getCoursesByInstructor() {
        global $db;

        return mysql_query("SELECT courses.*, course_types.name FROM $db[courses] as courses 
                            JOIN $db[course_types] as course_types ON courses.course_type_id=course_types.id
                            WHERE instructor_id='$this->user_id'");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do:

```
$u = new Student(1);
$courses = $u->getCoursesByInstructor();
```

But am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flight1/phpincludes/classes/students.class.php on line 54

Comment: Note -- don't use `global` to access the `$db` resource. Pass it as an argument to the method, or (*as likely your static methods will become instance, based on the answers here*) pass it to the constructor of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're function is a static function, and therefore you cannot use the `$this` pointer within it because it supposed to point to an object. So just remove the `static` keyword from your function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using static methods non-statically. Static methods are only bound to its class, but not to an object, thus `$this` is not available. This especially means, that `$this->userid`, that you use in `getCoursesByInstructor()`, is not valid. I recommend to make the method non-static.

```
public function getCoursesByInstructor() { /* your code here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` keyword from the functions you declared inside your `Student` class.

The `static` keyword is, simply put, used to indicate a function that is accessible without the need of creating an instance of that class. On the other hand, `$this` is used to refer to class instance variables. That's why those two don't go well togheter, you're trying to access an instance variable (by using `$this`) in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is you are requesting `$this` inside your static function. See this. You have $this->user_id inside the query.

```
return mysql_query("SELECT courses.*, course_types.name FROM $db[courses] as courses 
                            JOIN $db[course_types] as course_types ON courses.course_type_id=course_types.id
                            WHERE instructor_id='$this->user_id'");
```

To fix this issue you have to modify this function. I can suggest you following way.

```
public static function getCoursesByInstructor($userID) {
        global $db;

        return mysql_query("SELECT courses.*, course_types.name FROM $db[courses] as courses 
                            JOIN $db[course_types] as course_types ON courses.course_type_id=course_types.id
                            WHERE instructor_id='$userID'");
    }
```

And you have to change your other functions with the same theory.

Cheers !